# Interpret \n as new line when text file contains \n in the text

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file which contains **\n** (back-slash N) in the file's contents.
I want Python to interpret \n as a new line, rather than a literal \n string.

samplefile.txt contains

```
multi\nline
```

My Python code

```
file_path = "./samplefile.txt"

with open(file_path, "r") as f:
    contents = f.read()
    
print(contents)
```

The print statement currently outputs this:

```
multi\nline
```

But I want it to output this:

```
multi
line
```

After I read the file's contents, how can I get Python to interpret **\n** in the file's contents as a new line?

What I've tried:

```
contents = repr(contents).replace("\\n", "\n")
print(contents)
```

But that outputs:

```
'multi\
line
'
```

Expected output:

```
multi
line
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code you tried, just drop the call to [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr). It escapes the backslash, which is not what you want. So it's just this:

```
>>> content = r'multi\nline'
>>> print(content.replace("\\n", "\n"))
multi
line
```